Hole, YHWH and counterfactual present
Let's concentrate on the grammar aspect:
In the lyrics of "Celebrity Skin", Courtney Love varies Dante (the other one):

My name is Might-have-been
My name is Never-was
My name's Forgotten

And I immediately associated the folk etymology of YHWH:

I was
I am
I will be

of which I see the lyrics as a "poetic negation". But my shoehorning stands and falls with whether "might have been" can be interpreted as counterfactual present. Technically, tense is (modal) perfect.
Example: I have a Ph.D. (not in English, naturally!) but am no professor. Can you say about my present me "He might have been a professor [now]", extending counterfactual past to the present? Personally, I don't find this construction unnatural.

https://youtu.be/uBiewQrpBBA    Modal +present perfect  irrealis.

We usually use could have been when "extending counterfactual past to the present" - such as "I could have been a contender" (but currently I'm not, because that past never happened). We tend to use might have been more in reference to "still-indeterminate past" - such as "I might have left my phone down the pub" (but that past is unknown).

"Courtney Love varies Dante (the other one):" varies? What is varies Dante?

@Lambie: Love quotes Dante (not Alighieri, but Gabriel Rossetti) "The House of Life 97" - but not verbatim. (With the original, I wouldn't have had the association.)

"…varies Dante" still does not make sense. Do you mean cites or inspired by? And I think you should add Gabriel Rossetti to it. I was thinking of Alighieri, too. Not every learner is familiar with "the other one"

Firstly, I think you are mistaken about the connection between your quotations. "I was, I am, I will be" is a quote from Friedrich Nietzsche. It reflects his ideas about the eternal recurrence and the fluid, interconnected nature of time and existence. Although the Judeo-Christian scriptures describe the almighty God (YHWH) as infinite, they do so in somewhat different terms. A vocal critic of Christianity, Nietzsche was not referring to God with those words.
I don't see poetic negation in Nietzsche's statement "I was, I am, I will be". Leaving aside any philosophical meaning he derived from it and taking it at face value, there is nothing counterfactual about having a past, a present and a future. These are not mutually exclusive concepts.
Likewise, "My name is Might-have-been / My name is Never-was / My name's Forgotten" doesn't contain anything contradictory. It's clearly not speaking about a person literally having multiple names. They are slang names, and all seem to mean the same thing. "Might-have-been", and "never-was", as compound nouns, are commonly used to describe someone who failed at achieving fame. Saying someone is "forgotten" could mean the same, perhaps implying that maybe the speaker had a moment in the spotlight but never became sufficiently 'famous' to be remembered.
Your own example of "He might have been a professor [now]" is wrong. It sounds like you're trying to make a simple speculative statement (epistemic modality). If you think someone may have achieved something in the past, but you don't know for sure, you use the past tense ie "he may have done [x]". But if someone achieved becoming a professor in the past then they are a professor now, so there's no need to use incorrect tenses - you'd say "they may be a professor now". This is also not an example of a counterfactual statement. A counterfactual statement expresses something that is not the case, not simply something you do not know about. For that reason, counterfactual statements cannot be introduced by modals like "may", "might", or "must". An example of a counterfactual statement would be "if he had gone to university he would be a professor now".

I'm a German - the things you describe are exactly the subtilities you have problems with if you are not a native speaker. Thus I appreciate if someone goes the lengths to explain.
